# How can add subprojects dependancies to root project .classpath

Tags: gradle

I am trying to generate the root project .classpath with subproject dependancies. Found an example in oreilly-gradle-book-examples.

Can someone help me to convert following older gradle code block to latest gradle (2.2) version?

```
subprojectConfigurations = allprojects*.configurations*.matching {
  it.name in [ 'compile', 'runtime' ]
}
subprojectConfigurations.all.flatten().each {
  plusConfigurations << it
}
```

This is extracted from following source.
https://github.com/gradleware/oreilly-gradle-book-examples/blob/master/multiproject-eclipse-plugin/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

In gradle, subprojects are defined in another file named settings.gradle

You can find this file in your 
https://github.com/gradleware/oreilly-gradle-book-examples/blob/master/multiproject-eclipse-plugin/settings.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eddu. What I want is to generate the root project .classpath with subprojects dependancies. Someone can help to convert above code block for gradle 2.2?